# A simple Increasing Mathematical Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I actually tried to search this, I'm sure this basic algorithm is everywhere on internet, CS textbooks etc, but I cannot find the right words to search it.

What I want from this algorithm to do is write "A" and "B" with the limit always increasing by 2. Like I want it to write A 3 times, then B 5 times, then A 7 times, then B 9 times and so on. And I plan to have 100 elements in total.

Like: AAABBBBBAAAAAAABBBBBBBBB...

I only want to use a single "for loop" for the entire 100 elements starting from 1 to 100. And just direct/sort  "A" and "B" through "if/else if/ else".

I'm just asking for the basic mathematical algorithm behind it, showing it through any programming language would be better or redirecting me to such topic would also be fine.

Comment: repeat_times = repeat_times + 2, not the simplest solution? have a counter, use modulus, you do not need if else.

Comment: Thanks for responding, could you give me a brief example out of what you've suggest in a simple code snippet? How to use modulus to differentiate the same odd number, with which number that I should mod the counter?

Comment: This is an elementary process that doesn't deserve a specific name (can it even be called an algorithm ?)

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well, it can. Also don't belittle my beloved dear TBT named math problem.

Comment: @DolphinEugene see below for my answer in JavaScript for you to test on this page, no `if`. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:
There might be shorter answers, but I find this one easy to understand.
Basically, you keep a *bool* variable that will tell you if it's `A`'s turn or `B`s. Then we keep a variable `switch` that will tell us when we should switch between them. `times` is being updated with the repeated times we need to print the next character.

```
A_B = true
times = 3   // 3,5,7,9,...
switch = 3  // 3,8,15,24,...
for (i from 1 to 100)
    if (A_B)
        print 'A'
    else
        print 'B'
    if (i == switch)
        times += 2
        switch += times
        A_B = !A_B
```

Comment: But wouldn't it show like 3 A and 97 B? What I understood from your code is as long as A_B is what is when it's first stated, it'll keep show A. But when i comes to 3, the ot her if down there makes it A_B = not A_B and it stays that way 'till the end of the loop.

Comment: @DolphinEugene I changed it a bit to make it more clear. whenever `i` gets to the value of `switch` we are switching between `A` and `B`. Then, we are updating `switch` to the next time we should switch again.

Comment: When i is 1, it prints A because A_B is true

When i is 2, it prints A because A_B is true

When i is 3, it first print A, then it becomes equal of switch, increases "times" from 3 to 5. and increases "switch", "times" more. And makes A_B false

When i is 4, it goes to else because A_B is false now, and it keeps being false that way. Nothing change is that later, so the code make it write A again. It gets stuck on "else"

Comment: The part where `i==switch` is not inside the `else` block. It will enter the `if (i==switch)` again when `i` is 8 as we updated `switch` to be 8 last time.

Comment: Oh so the boolean varriable makes itself false/true. Let me try this on code.

Comment: Exactly, I added the explanation to the answer itself. Hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: Out of all codes/suggestions here, yours was the simplest yet the most effective, did what I wanted to do. Thanks @A.Sarid

Answer (score 0):

**Python:**

```
for n in range(1, 101):
    print "BA"[(int(sqrt(n)) % 2)],
```

The parity of the square roots of the integers follows that pattern. (Think that `(n+1)²-n² = 2n+1`.)

---

If you prefer to avoid the square root, it suffices to use an extra variable that represents the integer square root and keep it updated

```
r= 1
for n in range(1, 101):
    if r * r <= n:
        r+= 1 
    print "AB"[r % 2],
```

Comment: I'm lost at how you can diffrentiate AB in "" like I don't understand how it's gonna write AAABBBBB but not ABABABABAB  or is it a function of Phython?

Comment: @DolphinEugene: array indexing. (You can trust the code, it's real.)

Answer (score 0):

To get 100 groups of A and B with increasing length of 3, 5, 7 and so on, you can run this Python code:

```
''.join(('B' if i % 2 else 'A') * (2 * i + 3) for i in range(100))
```

The output is a string of 10200 characters.

If you want the output to have only 100 characters, you can use:

```
import math
''.join(('B' if math.ceil(math.sqrt(i)) % 2 else 'A') for i in range(2, 102))
```

Comment: 100 elements in total ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet you can test on this page. It is an example for about 500 letters totally, sure you can modify it for 100 letters. It is quite flexible that you can change the constants to produce lot of different strings in the same manner.

```js
var toRepeat = ['A', 'B'];
var result='', j, i=3;
var sum=i;
var counter = 0;
while (sum < 500) {
  j = counter % 2;
  result = result + toRepeat[j].repeat(i); 
  sum = sum + i;
  i = i + 2;
  counter++;
}
document.getElementById('hLetters').innerHTML=result;
console.log(result);
```

```html
    <div id="hLetters"></div>
```

If you want it to be exactly 500 / 100 letters, just use a `substring` function to trim off the extra letters from the end.

Answer (score -1):

In js you can start with somethink like this :

```
$res ="";

  count2 = 0;
for (i=2;i<100; i = i+2) {
  count = 0;
  alert(i);
  while (count < i ) {

    $res = $res.concat(String.fromCharCode(65+count2));
    count++;
  }
  count2++;
}

alert ($res);
```

Comment: I don't want specifically get the entire chars as what I've expected is that not to get the characters written, but I can use it in such difference ways.

Comment: it was just a example to start. Modify this code with your language and to get result expected. i concat a string and show in  alert to test my function on plnkr ^^